# Too many instances of this service are already running

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Installed application, but container is not getting downloaded. It keeps giving me the same error message (see below).

I had already restarted my iPad, mac and had also deleted the derived data and "iOS DeviceSupport" folder but nothing works.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've restarted my iPhone, deleted the app from it, restarted it again, restarted my Mac...was there something specific that worked for you?

Comment: when i was facing this issue i tried every thing restarting mac/ipad, deleting application but nothing was working

Answer (score 19):

Power Off and Power ON iPhone works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Please follow these steps:

Step 1: Restart your device.

Step 2: Restart the Xcode (not mandatory).

Working for me.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with your iPad RAM. Clean that.

To clean RAM:

1. Hold power button until shutdown bar appears.
2. Hold Home button until shutdown bar disappear.

Comment: This took a couple of tries, but did eventually work. It should be marked as the answer: even powering on/off doesn't resolve, but his does.